# In Office Add-ins, can i know which tenant the user belongs to?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, exchangewebservices, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I tried to get it by using [mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/web-services?product=outlook) but looks like it doesn't support the [GetUserSettings operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877096(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: I have created another answer. Does it help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found out a workaround.

Take the token returned by [getUserIdentityTokenAsync](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#getUserIdentityTokenAsync). It is a JWT Token that can be deserialized see for example [this site](https://jwt.io/).

The tenant id is present in various fields of the deserialized JSON (see red square in attachment). I tested it only with one Office365 tenant.

[image: JWT decoding]

Answer (score 1):

Office Outlook web add-ins are also supported for Exchange On Premise (2013+) and now Personal Microsoft Account (outlook.com). In these situations there is no notion of tenant so I do not think you can retrieve the [TenantId](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-your-Office-365-tenant-ID-6891b561-a52d-4ade-9f39-b492285e2c9b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

If your Office Addins uses Azure AD, then TenantId will be part of [the claims](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/) but your add-in will be only compatible to Office 365 accounts (except if you use the new [Azure v2.0 model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/)). The real negative impact is that your users will have to authenticate in the add-in using their Office365 account.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to know the tenant before I authenticate to Azure AD.